# Screen flicker/no screen and wireless problems after water spill

Tags: hardware-failure, lenovo-laptop

I have lots of problems with my Lenovo G470 after there was a water spill accident 3 months ago which caused half my keyboard to be damaged.

1. Recently the screen flickers or there will be totally no screen on boot.
2. There is one instant that after many tries, I got the screen to work but there is no network detected. But I know my wireless network works and that my computer's wireless is turned on.

Anyone can help with this? Is it worth it to get it repair? I don't think that water spills are covered by the warranty: can they detect it?

Answer (score 2):

From the issues you describe, I'd assume that the water managed to damage quite a few internal parts (namely, the ones responsible for video and wireless).

From Lenovo's [warranty policy](http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/l505-0010-01-en.pdf):

> This warranty does not cover the following:
>   [...]
>   failure or damage resulting from **misuse, accident**, modification, unsuitable physical or operating environment, natural disasters, power surges, or improper maintenance by you;

(emphasis mine). So I think you're out of luck here: the warranty does not cover water damage. You might want to send it to repair and get a quote, and see whether it's worth to repair it.

Answer (score 2):

This is more to add to Renan's answer than anything else.  He covered the fact that you can't expect Lenovo to foot the bill on this one, and did so very well.

> 3 months ago

That's part of the issue right there.  That, and attempting to get it to work without getting it fixed.  That may have bade the difference between just replacing the keyboard, and having to replace the keyboard as well as the motherboard.  Time is one of the enemies here.  Getting a laptop dry after a spill is paramount, and can still cost you a keyboard.  Most of the time there is just no getting the moisture out from between the three layers of plastic that make up the actual working components of the keyboard.  At all.  Ever.

But you've got 3 months of shorting contacts now.  3 months of making connections that were never supposed to have been made, and you are seeing the results.

So, the keyboard needs to be replaced.  That's first.  The unit needs to be disassembled, inspected, and possibly cleaned.  So, you should expect to pay at the very least, a diagnostic fee and the time to clean the unit... and that's just to find out if it will be worth it to repair.  From there, you will face either just replacing a keyboard, or replacing much more as well.